# How to make different object's UVs proportional between each other?

Tags: uv, uv-image-editor

I'm making some uv maps from several objects that share the same height.[image]

But when I do unwrap, the map scales towards the bounds of the "editing canvas".[image: the maps]

How can I unwrap this objects in a way that the maps end up proportional between each other?

Comment: You could join them, unwrap, then separate? Then you'll scale up the UVs keeping the same factor every time?

Comment: I could, but the easiest way to do it would be to create faces linking them, unwrap and then figure all the mess in the uv editor, I was hoping for a faster method.